Azure Application Gateway URL limitation
We have a custom app deployed in the Azure Gov Cloud, and that app is authenticated via Azure AD. After authentication, the app will redirect back to the custom app home page. In return, the system is passing an access and refresh token as part of the URL query string. The app URL is configured against the application gateway LB with a WAF policy. For a few B2B users, the access token and refresh payload size are larger than usual due to  that the gateway is returning a 414 status code. 
Are we aware of any settings in the app gateway to tackle this URL length limitation?

Can you once cross check and confirm that the App gateway is sending 414 and not backend? Can you please share the entire AccessLogs and FirewallLog where the HTTP status is 414 for better understanding of the issue?

As a work around i removed extra payload from URl and there after it is able  to run without issues
